# need to plot a 2D graph of the gray image intensity in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

what I am trying is to compare two gray scale images by ploting their intensity into graph. The code is bellow is for single image.

```
img11 = imread('img.bmp');
[rows cols ColorChannels] = size(img11); 
for i=1:cols
    for j=1:rows 
        intensityValue = img11(j,i);
    end
end
% below trying different plot method
plot(intensityValue);
plot(1:length(img11),img11);
plot(img11(:))
```

My expected result for two images is like below pictures: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhbGu.png)

not like
this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzjPl.png)

Comment: Do you mean something like `imshow` or `imagesc`?

Comment: One of those, plus `subplot`, should get you what you're looking for. If not, please edit your question to include more detailed information

Comment: Maybe just try to flatten the image matrix `plot(img11(:))`. Or if you interested in the distribution of gray values `histogram()` can be useful.

Comment: @mpaskov Got error

subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: @Johar Add updates (especially code) by editing your original question. It's easier to read everything in one place, you can't format code in comments, and comments are not guaranteed to be around forever so your clarifications may get lost.

Comment: @beaker, Thanks.  what I am trying is to compare two images by ploting their intensity into graph. The code is bellow is for single image.
 
img11 = imread('img.bmp');

[rows cols ColorChannels] = size(img11);


for i=1:cols
    for j=1:rows
        intensityValue = int8 (img11(j,i));
    end
end

plot(intensityValue);
plot(1:length(img11), img11);
plot(img11(:));

Comment: @Johar Why do you say "thanks" and then ignore what I've said? You have once again put your updates in a comment. Please click [edit] at the bottom of your original question and add clarifications and code there.

Comment: @beaker, you are correct. I forgot to edit my question. hope its ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code you should be able to do the following.

```
img11 = imread('img1.bmp');
img22 = imread('img2.bmp');
figure;
imagesc(img11); % verify you image

figure;
plot(img11(:)); hold on;
plot(img22(:));
```

Using the command `(:)` will flatten a matrix into a single vector starting at the top left and going down in columns. If that is not the orientation that you want you try to rotate/transpose the image (or try using `reshape()`, but it might be confusing at the start). Additionally, if your image has large variations in the pixel intensity moving average filter can be useful.

```
Len = 128;
smooth_vector = filter(ones(Len,1)/Len,1,double(img11(:)));
figure; plot(smooth_vector);
```

Comment: I ran your code. But my expected output should be like this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhbGu.png

Comment: I though it might be too 'noisy' that is why I suggested to add the smoothing function, the moving average filter.

Comment: Yes. There is noise in images. But i am trying to compare two extreme images. After running your code, the graph looks more like histogram. I want to show them as 2D line graph. 
Thanks :)

Comment: A histogram would show how often each gray value occurs in the image, which this code does not produce. This would produce, a plot with a graph with pixel-index on the x-axis and pixel value on the y-axis. Could upload the image and share a link, and I will have a look.

Comment: here is the link:

Comment: I meant the original image. Also that is what I expect to see. Now you can add the smoothing filter, which is the second part of the code, the larger the `Len` the smoother the curve would be.

Comment: I tried with different "len" value. But no other ways to make like the bellow image.

Comment: How do you want the pixel on the x-axis to be ordered?

Comment: I am not sure if order is important here. Just want to plot gray image's intensity values horizontally over x-axis. And show them as connected line.

Comment: That is exactly what this code produces. What you are seeing is that there is rapid and large difference between adjacent pixel. Try it a more simple [image](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHSm42ousCoAb05VM8Wq9VFSoweHkvuwpHF3OFwrzPqTodLWazIQ). I assume that the one you are currently using is 'Lena', which quite detailed.

Comment: Is this happening because we are taking every pixel intensity? Is it possible to have single line curve if we take the highest inensity in each column?

Comment: Well yes, you are plotting the intensity of every pixel, but with filter function you are averaging over multiple pixel. The picture has many different colors (of gray), to achieve shades and smooth transitions so you should expect to see the pixel intensity fluctuate. If you had an image with just two colors, with sharp transitions between colors it would look very different. This is a single line curve, I do not understand what you mean by that. Plotting the highest intensity in each columns is completely different thing.

Comment: I undertand your point. This is indeed a one line over every single row, if i am not wrong. I told you I am new. 

However I am also trying with improfile. Which also plot image intensity as a single line graph. Is it possible in improfile to give starting and ending point as parameter to show the the profile between that specified co-ordinates?